# Why does the new design use biohazard symbol for answered questions?

Tags: discussion, design

It's super creepy, and I don't see how it fits with the site or the rest of the design.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's meant to be the same symbol as the circular design around the figure in the top right of the page.  But I agree that it ends up looking just like the biohazard symbol.

Comment: The glowing green text over the top certainly helps imply a biohazard...

Answer (score 5):

It warns you not to read questions that have answers. They're hazardous to your health.

Answer (score 3):

Keen wrote:

> I think it's meant to be the same symbol as the circular design around
>   the figure in the top right of the page.

That's exactly why I used it. But I agree it may send the wrong message. In my original mockup I simply had the accepted answer background as a solid green.

Do you guys have any other suggestions? Keep in mind, it needs to be contained within a square shape, and easily identifiable, and not overwhelming the numbers on top of it.

I can always change it back to the solid green.

Comment: Perhaps something similar to the badge icons you've created. They are round like the Vote up/down buttons so it would be around the same pattern to have another round image in that same area.

Comment: I agree, you could also turn the badge icons upside down.

Comment: there are other significant scifi shapes you can think of that may work? I prefer not to re-use the badge shape.

Comment: @jin maybe you could start with a restyled star-fleet logo, something like a [Escutcheon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escutcheon_%28heraldry%29) for a Fantasy touch, you could alway add a pour of Greek letters.

Answer (score 1):

The design on the upper right actually comes really, and I mean REALLY close to the symbol for the triple Goddes in Wicca (the maiden, mother, and crone).  Personally, I think it's beautiful, but question whether religious iconography is appropriate in this case.  I like it, but it might offend some of various faiths when they find out what the three crescent moons often symbolize.

As for the biohazard symbol, I honestly think that should be changed.  It's a warning sign, something with negative connotations, and I think the symbol for an answer should be a positive sign.

But I waited to say anything because I think the design for SF&F looks great overall and know it's taken a lot of work to create.

Comment: I was not aware of the symbol for the Wiccan Goddesses. I did a quick google search just now and found the symbol for [Triple Crescent Moon](http://bit.ly/uWozCQ) and I can see the resemblance. My inspiration for the logo came from looking at numerous alchemy and rune circles during my design research. I wanted to capture the geometry and the mystical feeling. The "crescent moon" shapes I picked really came from the biohazard sign. I thought it'd be neat if the logo is comprised of something magical and scifi-ish.

Comment: I'm not offended by religious symbology but I personally find the bio-hazard-like picture not very aesthetically pleasing. I think it's the worst - by far - image in the new design. I like solid background blocks ala StackOverflow much better

Comment: Actually, the more I think of it, the more I think that anyone who might take offense at Wiccan symbolism is likely not to know anything about Wiccan symbolism.  (This reminds me of a time a Christian fundamentalist friend of mine was, in a large group, telling us all about how it was really weird when she and her family were someplace and a number of Wiccans came out to start a celebration for an Esbat and she had absolutely no idea that one of our mutual friends, who was standing next to me was a Wiccan - but I had known for years because I knew the things that gave her (the Wiccan) away.)